# Python3 BeautifulSoup insert each tag (nested too) in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, nested

I'm trying to parse some HTML with BeautifulSoup library and what I want to do is insert each tag with its contents in a dictionary but I don't want to add nested tags contents as a whole, instead, I want all nested childs of a tag to be added in the dictionary separately. I've tried so many different ways and closest I've reached is insert every tags contents (nested too) in the dictionary. Forgive me if what I wrote above is rather confusing, you'll understand what I mean right away.

HTML code I'm using for this little project is the one that follows (taken from https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ website):

```
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
```

What I want to have as a result is the one that follows:

```
{0: <title>The Dormouse's story</title>,
 1: <body>
 2: <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>,
 3: <p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were,
 4: <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
 5: <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>and,
 6: <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>;,
 7: and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>,
 8: <p class="story">...</p>}
```

This is the code that got me the closest so far,

```
tags = []                                                  
for tag in soup.find_all():
    tags.append(tag.name)

elements = {}
for i, elem in enumerate(soup.find_all(tags)):
    elements[i] = elem.contents, elem.atts
```

And this is the result of it when I call elements in python3 console,

```
>>> elements
{0: ([<head><title>The Dormouse's storytitle</title>head</head>, '\n', <body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's storyb</b>p</p>
<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsiea</a>,
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Laciea</a> and
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tilliea</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.p</p>
<p class="story">...p</p>
body</body>, 'html'], None), 
 1: ([<title>The Dormouse's storytitle</title>, 'head'], None), 
 2: (["The Dormouse's story", 'title'], None), 
 3: (['\n', <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's storyb</b>p</p>, '\n', <p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsiea</a>,
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Laciea</a> and
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tilliea</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.p</p>, '\n', <p class="story">...p</p>, '\n', 'body'], None), 
 4: ([<b>The Dormouse's storyb</b>, 'p'], None), 
 5: (["The Dormouse's story", 'b'], None), 
 6: (['Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were\n', <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsiea</a>, ',\n', <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Laciea</a>, ' and\n', <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tilliea</a>, ';\nand they lived at the bottom of a well.', 'p'], None), 
 7: (['Elsie', 'a'], None), 
 8: (['Lacie', 'a'], None), 
 9: (['Tillie', 'a'], None), 
 10: (['...', 'p'], None)}
```

Which is clearly not what I need because nested tags are getting repeated over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
'''

element = {}
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
title = soup.title.extract()
soup.head.decompose()
body = soup.body.extract()
temp = str(title) + '\n' + str(body)
for i in temp.split('\n'):
    element[str(temp.split('\n').index(i))] = i

for key, value in element.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Output:

```
0 <title>The Dormouse's story</title>
1 <body>
2 <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
3 <p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
4 <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
5 <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
6 <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
7 and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
8 </body>
```